# Hide/show expands all divs when I want it to open one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am making a page that is responsive and is pulling content from wordpress. There are 4 photos and in each photo is a button displaying "whats in the bag" and "player history." When you click each button I want it to display the hidden div content below the photo. Right now when I click the button it opens all of the divs instead of the 1 player I want to show. Here is the script I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
return false;
});

});

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".slidingDiv2").hide();
$(".show_hide2").show();

$('.show_hide2').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
return false;
});

});
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="popup-open">
    <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="show_hide popup">WHAT'S IN THE BAG</a><br/>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="show_hide2 popup">PLAYER HISTORY</a>


    </div>
    </div>  

<div class="slidingDiv">
  <div id="tabs-1">
                    <div class="witb-tab">

                        <?php 

                        $fields = CFS()->get('witb');

                        if($fields) :
                            foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
                            <div class="row">
                                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $field['cta_link'];?>">
                                    <div class="image">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $field['product_image'];?>" alt="<?php echo $field['product_name'];?>">
                                        <a target="_blank" class="product-name" href="<?php echo $field['cta_link'];?>" title="<?php echo $field['product_name'];?>">
                                    <?php echo $field['product_name'];?>
                                </a>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="show_hide" style="float:right;">CLOSE</a>
            </div>


  </div>

<div class="slidingDiv2">
   <div class="column left">

            <!-- post thumbnail -->
            <?php                       
                if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    the_post_thumbnail('profile-thumb');
                }
                // Check if post thumbnail exist
                else {
                    $values = CFS()->get('gender');
                    if (is_array($values)) {
                        foreach ($values as $value => $label) {
                            //echo '<h1 style="color:red">' . $value . '</h1>';
                            echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/thumb-'. $value . '.png"' . 'alt="thumbnail" />';
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <!-- /post thumbnail -->

            <div class="player-biography">
                <?php echo CFS()->get('player_biography'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column right">
  <div id="tabs-2">
                    <div class="content-wrap"><?php the_content(); // Dynamic Content ?></div>
                </div>
             <a href="#" class="show_hide2" style="float:right;">CLOSE</a>    
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the selector `.className` affects all elements in the DOM with such class. What you will want to do is go from your clicked `<a>` and use the structure of your DOM to get the element you want by looking at it's parent's parent:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

In this case you only need a single `show-hide` class and a single `slideingDiv` class. It's not necessary to have `slideingDiv`, `slideingDiv2`, `slideingDiv3`, ... As it takes away the point of using classes in the first place, and they might as would be ids. The structure is the same, simply with the same classes:

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div id="tabs-1">
        ...    
        <a href="#" class="show_hide" style="float:right;">CLOSE</a>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div id="tabs-2">
        ...    
        <a href="#" class="show_hide" style="float:right;">CLOSE</a>
    </div>
 </div>
 ...
```

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3L93dbms/9/)

Comment: I don't understand one thing. In the above code, he mentioned two different classes as .slidingDiv and .slidingDiv2 which should work ideally as both class names are unique but you are defining it with a single class name all together.

Comment: @SridharGudimela Classes are not meant to be unique, they should be repeated. Otherwise you would use an id instead. So yes I'm defining it simply with the class `slidingDiv`, which both elements would have, rather than two separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting the class in your on-click function try using "this". You also dont need more than one ready function. Just so you know, the problem with your code is that you're targeting all elements of the class. You could also use IDs to target specific elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

   $('.show_hide').click(function(){
      $(this).parents('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
      return false;
   });
   $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
   $(".show_hide2").show();

   $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
      $(this).parents('.slidingDiv2').slideToggle();
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried using your code and it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: what about it didnt work? was there an error? did the wrong thing happen?

Comment: i edited it. its not an ideal solution, i would have structured the page a little differently, it should work though

Comment: Nothing happened. The div remained hidden.

Comment: try it with the edited code. I cant try it for you unfortunately and the HTML is a little hard to read. Give it a shot with the "parents()" method in there like I have above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `this` selector.

let's say you have something like:

```
<div class="item">
    <h1>Item1</h1>
    <div class="show_hide">
        Popping in and out 1.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <h1>Item2</h1>
    <div class="show_hide">
        Popping in and out 2.
    </div>
</div>
```

you can do

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.show_hide').slideToggle();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rvasu35/)

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.show_hide').hide();

  $('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.show_hide').slideToggle();
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <h1>Item1</h1>
  <div class="show_hide">
    Popping in and out 1.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <h1>Item2</h1>
  <div class="show_hide">
    Popping in and out 2.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works but when I add it on its own but when I try to add the html <h1> tag into the div class popup open div it does not work.

Comment: you have to have something visible to be clicked, so you can't move the `h1` inside the hidden `div`.

Comment: The div where I added the H1 isn't hidden.

Comment: how are you trying to add it? I think I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Right now in the 2 buttons sit in <div class="popup-open"></div> so I need the 2 buttons or links to display in there. When I move your <h1> tag in there it doesn't work anymore. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you have to update the jQuery selector to your own div name. so instead of `$('.item').click()` make it `$('.popup-open').click()` or whatever name the div you want the click to happend on is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // hide all divs class starts with slidingDiv
   $("div[class^='slidingDiv']").hide();
   // show all anchor class starts with show_hide
   $("a[class^='show_hide']").show();


  // anchor click event
    $(".title > a[class^='show_hide']").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent to reload
      // slide up all divs starts with slidingDiv but not the slidingDiv with index with <a> .. that mean if you click a with index() 0  it will hide all slidingDiv divs and show slidingDiv with index 0  and 1 for 1 and son on
      $("div[class^='slidingDiv']").not($("div[class^='slidingDiv']").eq($(this).index())).slideUp();
      $("div[class^='slidingDiv']").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ujac6oas/1/)

more clear demo

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ujac6oas/3/)

use this code instead of all your js code you posted

be sure to include jquery  inside `<head></head>` or before closing `</body>`  and after that run your code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ok complete code inside `<head></head>`  or before `</body>` should be like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       // hide all divs class starts with slidingDiv
       $("div[class^='slidingDiv']").hide();
       // show all anchor class starts with show_hide
       $("a[class^='show_hide']").show();


      // anchor click event
        $(".title > a[class^='show_hide']").on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); // prevent to reload
          // slide up all divs starts with slidingDiv but not the slidingDiv with index with <a> .. that mean if you click a with index() 0  it will hide all slidingDiv divs and show slidingDiv with index 0  and 1 for 1 and son on
          $("div[class^='slidingDiv']").not($("div[class^='slidingDiv']").eq($(this).index())).slideUp();
          $("div[class^='slidingDiv']").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed. This code caused the link to open in a new page.

Comment: @sizemattic I believe it won't .. please try it again with last update .. sorry my bad eq($(this).index()))  should be eq($(this).index()) .. try it now

Comment: It is still doing the same thing.

Comment: The 1st demo you created in jfiddle is something I am looking to do. I am not familiar with jfiddle but your code works in there but when I add it to my site it does not work. On the left is an onload option. Is there a certain library I should be using? Beginner here so sorry if I am not clear on this.

Comment: Could you please post the script source in the jfiddle? IT got cut off in the comment.

Comment: @sizemattic do you use separated file .js? or just run it as <script> in index page??

Comment: Running it in my header file.

Comment: @sizemattic  ok .. so before </body>   .. put the line of <script src="to_include_jquery"> in my answer  and then <script> // your code here  </script>