# jQuery merge different id's function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in the jQuery. I have to perform the same function on some links in a paragraph, affecting some images.

All links got an id and img too.

This is the example code:

```
$("#link1").hover(function () {
    $("#img1").removeClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $("#img1").addClass("hover");
});

$("#link2").hover(function () {
    $("#img2").removeClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $("#img2").addClass("hover");
});
```

And so on.
Do you know if there is a better way to avoid rewriting every time the same code for all the items?

Comment: provide html .. or look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509574/hide-show-expands-all-divs-when-i-want-it-to-open-one-at-a-time/33510181?noredirect=1#comment54805338_33510181

Comment: in your case use classes instead of Ids and try to find a way in jquery to relate the elements you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `starts with` selector. Looks for all the elements in the DOM that starts with ID = 'link' and target the corresponding `<img>` elements using the `replace()` method.

```
 $(document).find("[id^='link']").hover(function () 
{ 
    $("#" + this.id.replace("link","img")).removeClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("link","img")).addClass("hover");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n95sz5t1/2/

Comment: I'd suggest `this.id` rather than invoking jQuery to retrieve the `id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop

```
for (var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
  $("#link" + i).hover(function () {
    $("#img" + i).removeClass("hover");
  }, function () {
    $("#img"+ i).addClass("hover");
  });
}
```

That's the best I can offer without knowing the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
var handler = {
  attr: 'target',
  klass: 'hover',
  in : function() {
    var targetSelector = $(this).data(handler.attr);
    $(targetSelector).addClass(handler.klass);
  },
  out: function() {
    var targetSelector = $(this).data(handler.attr);
    $(targetSelector).removeClass(handler.klass);
  }
};

$('.trigger').hover(handler.in, handler.out);
```

```css
div {
  margin: 25px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #000;
}
img {
  margin: 5px;
}
.hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<div>

  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#img-1">link 1</a>

  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#img-2">link 2</a>

  <a href="#" class="trigger" data-target="#img-3">link 3</a>

</div>

<div>

  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" id="img-1">

  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" id="img-2">

  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" id="img-3">

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [["#link1", "#img1"], ["#link2", "#img2"]].map(function(set){
     $(set[0]).hover(function(){
       $(set[1]).removeClass("hover");
     }, function() {
       $(set[1]).addClass("hover");
     }  
 })
```

The other answer is obviously kind of the same. If your elements are continuously numbered its probably the close to driest you will get.
If the naming is a little more "dynamic" you can use above and add all the combinations of link and image to it.

Comment: Don't use `Array.map`  and ignore its result, you meant to use `Array.forEach`